# Check if Internet Explorer are running with administrator rights with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I´d like to check if the Internet Explorer are running with administrator rights.

I´d like to use jquery to do it, or js.

Any help?

Comment: not possible I'm afraid. javascript has no access to the browser code except through api's

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: I need that becouse I have to install a .cab and I need administrator rights to install this .cab.